# $.getJSON() call throwing error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, getjson

I can't figure out why .getJSON is throwing an error when the call to the parent function is made via a conditional statement. When the if statement is commented out, there does not seem to be an issue and .getJSON gets called. However, I want the user to complete their input (indicated by pressing enter).

**The HTML**

```
<div class="text-center searchBar">
  <form action="">
    <input type="text" id="searchText" />
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container displayResults"> </div>
```

**The Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#searchText').keyup(function(e) {
     var searchItem = $('#searchText').val();
     var link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&exlimit=max&inprop=url&generator=search&gsroffset=&format=json&formatversion=2&callback=?&gsrsearch=' + searchItem;

     if(e.which == 13) { //if user returns enter key
      wikiCall(link);
     }    
   });
});

function wikiCall(wikiLink) {  
  $.getJSON(wikiLink, function(searchResults) {      
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.query.pages.length; i++) {
      $(".displayResults").append("<div class='searchResultsContainer'><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:150%; margin-bottom:100px;'>" + searchResults.query.pages[i].title + "</span><br></br>" + searchResults.query.pages[i].extract + "</div>");
      $(".displayResults").append("<br>");
    }
  }).fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,error){
    alert(textStatus+": "+error);
  });
}
```

Comment: You might wanna try to disable the form submit event. ```$('.searchBar form').on('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; });``` to avoid the form submit when the user presses enter. Also check if the response has the ```query``` key before appending the data to the body.

Comment: @LucasFerreira Thank you, avoiding the form submit when enter was pressed did the trick.

Comment: @fzxt The .fail() was not giving me much to work with to decipher what the error was. The alert shown was: error: error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your software and I get only one mistake: keyup instead of keypress plus stop propagation.

In the following your code:

```js
function wikiCall(wikiLink) {
  $.getJSON(wikiLink, function(searchResults) {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.query.pages.length; i++) {
      $(".displayResults").append("<div class='searchResultsContainer'><span style='font-weight:bold; font-size:150%; margin-bottom:100px;'>" + searchResults.query.pages[i].title + "</span><br></br>" + searchResults.query.pages[i].extract + "</div>");
      $(".displayResults").append("<br>");
    }
  }).fail(function(jqxhr,textStatus,error){
    alert(textStatus+": "+error);
  });
}
$(function () {
  $('#searchText').keypress(function(e) {
    var searchItem = $('#searchText').val();
    var link = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts|info&exintro&exlimit=max&inprop=url&generator=search&gsroffset=&format=json&formatversion=2&callback=?&gsrsearch=' + searchItem;

    if(e.which == 13) { //if user returns enter key
      wikiCall(link);
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>


<div class="text-center searchBar">
    <form action="">
        <input type="text" id="searchText" />
    </form>
</div>

<div class="container displayResults"> </div>
```

The sequence of events when you type a character is:
keydown , keypress,  keyup .

For the first two events you have the possibility to prevent, while you cannot prevent the character typed on keyup event.

The keyup event is the last event for which you listen and you can only say: ok, this is the character I take an action but I cannot prevent the effect of this charcter, like form submitting.

When you type new line the results of the three events are:

keydown    keyCode=13 which=13 charCode=0

keypress   keyCode=13 which=13 charCode=13

keyup      keyCode=13 which=13 charCode=0

Comment: I was treating them kind of the same: keyup, keypress, keydown. I'm glad that I'm able to suppress the default using keypress but I'm confused as to why the same cannot be done using keyup.

Comment: I figured out the answer to my own question above: keyup is fired AFTER the submission, and therefore cannot be canceled.

Comment: @CodingerSK I updtaed the answer: yes on keyup you cannot stop the form submit.